# django: NULL error on model field despite default value

Tags: django

My model class is defined as follows: [django 5.0]

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    """
    ORM representing vendors

    Relationships:
    A vendor may have many documents
    """

    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        db_default='',
        default='',
    )
    logo_uri = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        db_default='',
        default='',
    )
    web_url = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        db_default='',
        default=None,
    )
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        null=False,
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"
    
    class Meta:
        ordering =  ["created_on"]
        verbose_name = "vendor"
        verbose_name_plural = "vendors"
```

I am using MySQL and have checked the database DDL - the default value for specified columns is set as ''. If I insert using a SQL statement directly in MySQL it works fine and default values are assigned as appropriate -

```
INSERT INTO `core_vendor`
(`name`,
`created_on`)
VALUES
('TES',
  NOW()
);
```

However when I programatically try to insert via django -

```
vendor = Vendor()
vendor.name='TES2'
vendor.web_url=None
vendor.save()
```

I receive an error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'web_url' cannot be null")
```

Though `web_url` has a default value assigned at django and DB level. Any thoughts on where I am incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `db_default` is used on case the value is *missing*, but here you have set the `default=None`. `db_default` is thus what Django will generate as SQL when constructing the table. It will thus write something like

```
CREATE TABLE vendor (
 -- …
 web_url varchar(255) DEFAULT ''
)
```

but then, because of the `default=None`, it will make a query:

```
INSERT INTO vendor (web_url)
VALUES (NULL);
```

since you pass a value explicitly, it thus errors.

This is also explained in the documentation on [**`db_default=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_default):

> If both `db_default` and `Field.default` are set, **`default` will take precedence when creating instances in Python code**. `db_default` will still be set at the database level and will be used when inserting rows outside of the ORM or when adding a new field in a migration.

Comment: Thanks - I tried changing the value to `default=''` and I get the same error. If I set `null=True` then I do not get an error, though that is not what I want.

Comment: Ok - I figured out that if I set the value of `web_url=None` explicitly then it gives me this error. If I do a check for None and skip setting `web_url` entirely then it does not error out. So for some reason, the explicit None overrides the default value - not sure if this is a bug or intentional

Comment: @SeaSky: no that is intended behavior. There is a difference between `None`, and *not* specifying a value. For that `django.db.models.DEFER` is used internally.

Comment: Thank you! This clarifies quite a few things for me.